# N to N relationship using three source tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm a student and I'm making a project, but  I have a problem, that I cannot resolve. I've got one table with rows imported from csv file, one table with facts (GunViolences) and one with dimension (Categories - dead and injured). In the original table (imported from csv file) I've got table description, and there are long strings, which have substrings dead or injured. And now I have to connect in some way table of facts with a table of dimensions, depending on category of violence. I've created another table called ViolenceCategories to connect these tables by IDs, but I don't know how can I fill this table.

Structure:

Table FromCSV

```
id, date, description, address  
1,12-01-2002, Shot|shotgun, address1  
2,19-04-2003, injured, address2  
3, 21-10-2004, shot|injured, address3
```

Table GunViolence

```
id, date, address  
1, 12-01-2002, address1  
2,19-04-2003, address2  
3, 21-10-2004, address3
```

Table DimCategories

```
id, category  
1, shot  
2, injured
```

Table ViolenceCategories

```
idFact, idDim  
1,1  
2,2  
3,2  
3,1
```

How can I fill table VIolenceCategories?

EDIT
I've created another table to separate values of column with description

Table DimDescription

```
id, desc1, desc2
1, Shot, shotgun
2, injured, null
3, shot, injured
```

Comment: The problem is your column `description` in your table `FromCSV`. It contains delimited data. You need to normalise your data by using another table to manage to many to many relationship.

Comment: Just to clarify, as it's not clear, you wanting to pick each value in your pipe-delimited string held in the `FromCSV.Description` column to establish the relationship held in table `ViolenceCategories` between tables `GunViolence` and `DimCategories`?

Comment: No, I need only information if there were fatalities or injured persons. I'll edit my post in a minute

Comment: The problem is, you want 2 columns in your result, `desc1` and `desc2`. Could your table `FromCSV` has 3 delimited values in the column `description`? If so, what you are you expected as your results then? Like I said, fix your design.

Comment: no, there's maximum two values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server 2016 and newer you can use table operator `STRING_SPLIT()` to achieve this. That function will split a delimited string in a record into new rows for each substring. Consider:

```
SELECT *
FROM FromCSV
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(description, '|') AS descriptions


+----+------------+---------------------+----------+-------------+
| id |    date    |     description     | address  |    value    |
+----+------------+---------------------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | 12-01-2002 | Shot|shotgun        | address1 | Shot        |
|  1 | 12-01-2002 | Shot|shotgun        | address1 | shotgun     |
|  2 | 19-04-2003 | three shots|injured | address2 | three shots |
|  2 | 19-04-2003 | three shots|injured | address2 | injured     |
|  3 | 21-10-2004 | shot|injured        | address3 | shot        |
|  3 | 21-10-2004 | shot|injured        | address3 | injured     |
+----+------------+---------------------+----------+-------------+
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cf448/2)

Turning this into an Insert statement to fill your `ViolenceCategories` table would look like:

```
INSERT INTO ViolenceCategories
SELECT t1.id, t2.id
FROM
(
    SELECT id, value
    FROM FromCSV
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(description, '|') AS descriptions
) t1
INNER JOIN DimCategories t2 ON t1.value = t2.category
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6b763/3)

Comment: sorry, but maybe I wrote it incomprehensibly. I don't know how to fulfil Table ViolenceCategories, when I fulfilled tables DimCategories and GunViolence using data from table FromCSV. How can I connect Fact with dimension

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you mean by "Fulfill". Do you mean "fill". like how to write an insert statement from your `FromCSV` to your `ViolenceCategories`?

Comment: yes, sorry for my English,  I had to write fill. I've two tables one with facts about violence (id, date and address) and the second one with dimensions (id and description). And now using data from the table FromCSV I want to connect id of violence with id of dimension to describe if there were fatalities or injured persons. And btw. thanks in advance for your trying to help

Comment: That makes sense to me. I've updated my answer to include the INSERT statement that would follow from the SELECT I provided. I believe it's what you are after.